# How do I Ignore values using Automapper map view model to model using ReverseMap

Tags: entity-framework, automapper

I have an entity with 5 fields with 2 that are meant to be "read only". I am using Automapper to map my entity to a view model. There are situations where the view model "read only" fields will be null. How do I always prevent those fields from being written back to my entity and overwriting the read only data? I would like to do this in my Automapper config.

In my config below I want to prevent "CallTime" from being overwritten in my record in the DB. (I am never creating a new record so I am not worried about ever writing to that field)

```
  cfg.CreateMap<Order, OrderVM>()
            .ForMember(d => d.CountrySelectList, opt => opt.Ignore())
            .ForMember(d => d.IsDelete, opt => opt.Ignore())
            .MaxDepth(4)
            .ReverseMap()
            .ForMember(d => d.FeedSource,opt=>opt.Ignore())
            .ForMember(d => d.CallTime, opt=>opt.Ignore());
```

I know I can manual deal with this by various means in my other code but would prefer to do it in the config area.

Comment: is using the ReverseMap feature a must?

Comment: In this situation the benefits of using ReverseMap outweigh the hassle of dealing with this issue.

Comment: the hassle of dealing with the issue = having to create a map from OrderVM to Order?